# .slugignore does not work in Heroku deployment

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a project in Heroku.

This is my `.slugignore`:

```
/source/coffee/
/source/scss/
/source/jade/
/gruntfile.coffee
/README.md
```

When I execute `git push heroku master` command appears the following message:

```
(...)

-----> Deleting 5 files matching .slugignore patterns.
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.10.21
       Using npm version: 1.3.11
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm

(...)
```

But when I clone the project the files that should be ignored are still there.

I leave also the project tree:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slugignore only controls what ends in the app slug, not what is in the Heroku repo. So if you ran `heroku run bash` and checked with `ls`, you would find that the things in `.slugignore` were not there. Use .gitignore if there's something you don't want to include in the git repo.

[Full docs on Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-slugignore).

Comment: Thank you! But is it normal that the folder `node_modules` and other folders and files of slug occupy 9MB, and in Heroku occupy 17.8MB?

Comment: @benatespina the difference in `node_modules` could be due to the size of compiled native dependencies on Heroku's 64-bit linux platform vs your development environment.